# What is the code for hiding install.packages() in R?

Tags: r

Currently I'm calling for install.packages() every time I'm loading a library in R, since my laptop seems to always giving me an error message if I don't do that, but I'm kinda sure that I've already installed those packages while setting up RStudio. Is there a way for me to enter those install.packages() on top of every RMD file and then hide them? I've heard that some code could do it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should definitely not have to `install.packages` every time. Take a look in the directories that get returned from entering `.libPaths()` and see if you have the package directories there. It would also help us debug your issue if you could describe the error message you get from doing `library(packagename)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install a package each time. Simply run `library(whateverpackage)` and that's it. You can always `suppressMessages(library(whateverpackage))` You can see currently loaded packages using `sessionInfo()`